# Create SVN "sub" repo

Tags: svn

One of our developers has asked me to create a subrepo of a repo currently on our SVN box.

/usr/local/subversion/project/proj

He wants

/usr/local/subversion/project/proj2

I looked into a simple mkdir /usr/local/subversion/project/proj2, but will SVN recognise it, and will everything be hunky-dory?  Thanks.

Comment: If you explain *why* nested repositories are desired instead of a single repository or independent repositories, people may be able to offer better answers. As it stands now, you might be describing an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Nested repositories are not possible in Subversion.

You can serve multiple repositories using the Parent Path option for `mod_dav_svn` and `svnserve`, but that requires that the repositories be in *sibling* (parallel) directories, not subdirectories.

Comment: Hi, I thought they were in parallel directories, both under project, no?

Comment: You specifically said "subrepo" which implies that you want to nest. If you use the Parent Path options and point that at `/usr/local/subversion/project` it will work, but URLs may change.

Comment: Sorry, sloppy wording on my part.  I meant what I now know to be called 'sibling'.

Answer (score 0):

A plain Unix mkdir in the filesystem repository directory won't work, you need to use svn commands. For example, `svn mkdir` with a URL, or from a working copy you could use mkdir followed by `svn add` and `svn commit`.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html